# Detecting when user leaves page in Page_Load event

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

When a user leaves a page it fires of the Page_Load event again. How can I tell in code_behind that this is happening so in can avoid running the custom functions as the code in the Page_Load does not really need to be ran when leaving the page?

Comment: How is the user leaving the page because just swapping to another url via an a href wouldnt fire a postback?

Comment: switching tab pages in an asp.net tab container. I have a different page in (iframe) on each tab. So when a tab is activated it fires the Page_Load event from the previous tab.

Comment: Use Luke's answer !ispostback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a user leaves a page it fires of the Page_Load event again

What do you mean by leaving a Page? Closing the browser or clicking Back button on browser? Or moving to another Page? `Page_Load` method is fired when on Loading Page or when Postback occurs on the same Page, but not leaving it.

Before you start any operations, you can (and you should) ensure that client is still connected and use `HttpResponse.IsClientConnected` property.

The IsClientConnected property returns false when the following conditions are true:

1. The connection to the client was terminated. This can occur if the Close method was invoked, or if the client stopped execution of the Web page or browsed to another page.
2. The HttpWorkerRequest object that is handling the request is null or the HttpWorkerRequest.IsClientConnected method returns false. If a custom HttpWorkerRequest object handles the request, then the HttpWorkerRequest.IsClientConnected method might be set based on custom criteria. For example, the custom worker request might force a time-out after a period of time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx

**EDIT**

Switching tabs usually fires normal **Postback**, to detect it you should use:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostback)
    {
       //this is first load of this page
    }
}
```

Comment: switching tab pages in an asp.net tab container. I have a different page in (iframe) on each tab. So when a tab is activated it fires the Page_Load event from the previous tab.

Comment: @tszro. Ok, so I edited my answer. I hope first part of my answer can be also usefull.

Comment: After further investigatioin, the page has been initially loaded in each tab so the IsPostBack only evaluates to true on time. Then when the tab pages are activated the web page in previous tab evaluates IsPostBack = False because the page was already loaded. So I think I have to set a session variable to hold the active tab page name and use that to (run or not run) specific code in each page. Don't know if this makes any sense to anyone out there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking for the [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property:

```
 private void Page_Load()
 {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Any code here will only run the first time the page is loaded  
    }
}
```